# curl fail when request in server

Tags: php, curl, server, request, restful-url

I have 1 REST api :

```
http://www.animemobile.com/service/v2/mobile2.php?episode_id=47272
```

I use curl to request it, in my PC with xampp, it works well and returns the correct results. This is results from my PC with xampp:

```
[
 {
    "Title":"English Subbed",
    "link":"\/[HorribleSubs] Pascal-sensei - 01 [720p]_af.mp4?
            st=14GwNjlMxuI8524DS56IUA&e=1495183034"
 }
]
```

I use

```
/[HorribleSubs] Pascal-sensei - 01 [720p]_af.mp4?
            st=14GwNjlMxuI8524DS56IUA&e=1495183034
```

to create a link as:

```
http://st2.anime1.com/[HorribleSubs]%20Pascal-sensei%20-
%2001%20[720p]_af.mp4?st=14GwNjlMxuI8524DS56IUA&e=1495183034.
```

This link is a video that can be played when request from browser (now).

But when I use the curl in my SERVER, it still works well but does not return the correct results. This is results from my Server:

```
[
 {
    "Title":"English Subbed",
    "link":"\/[HorribleSubs] Pascal-sensei - 01 [720p]_af.mp4?
            st=ghDP4290fsBNdmfsSKCD=1495195645"
 }
]
```

When I use

```
/[HorribleSubs] Pascal-sensei - 01 [720p]_af.mp4?
            st=ghDP4290fsBNdmfsSKCD=1495195645
```

to create a link as:

```
http://st2.anime1.com/[HorribleSubs]%20Pascal-sensei%20-
%2001%20[720p]_af.mp4?%20st=ghDP4290fsBNdmfsSKCD=1495195645.
```

It doesn't play on my browser.

This is my curl:

```
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
    curl_setopt($c, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    $headers = [
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch',
        'Accept-Language: vi,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6',
        'Cache-Control: max-age=0',
        'Connection: keep-alive',
        'Cookie: __cfduid=d7bf11c717fbcd54ec9b259e301a966d71480412679',
        'Host: www.animemobile.com',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36'
    ];
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $data = curl_exec($c);
```

What is the problem here? Please help me!

Edit1: If you want to test the results, you need to request the REST-api again because it had limited time for link to be created. Important that request the REST-api on PC returns correct results but request from server returns wrong results although they look very similar!

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: The response for "st" parameter seems to be a random string. You can try it by clicking on your API link in your browser and refresh a few times - [here](http://www.animemobile.com/service/v2/mobile2.php?episode_id=47272)

Comment: @Ravistm In sever it seems to return true but link in the result returned is non-existent.

Comment: @Arbels It was born in the api and there exist on their server, if you change the string that will not work anywhere.

Comment: can you edit your question and write the expected output? how it should be and whats wrong in it

Comment: @Ravistm Two results returned from the server and my pc is different, when retrieved the value named link in the returned results and pairing with st2.com prefix to create 1 link and insert the link that should the browser then it can run the video in the link. also with the results from the server, then it is not running. Sorry for my poor English !